# ruby on rails - how to post tagsinput and get an array as result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i created a field called tags_speciality

Here is my migration file:

```
class AddSpecialityToSubdomains < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    add_column :subdomains, :tag_speciality, :string, array: true
 end
end
```

Then i added on my view file the field:

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_speciality, data: {role: 'tagsinput'},  multiple: true %>
<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

After submit the form i get that result:

```
[["tag1,tag2,tag3"]]
```

But look like that would be better get this result:

```
[["tag1","tag2","tag3"]]
```

How can i achive that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this on your result:

```
arr = [["tag1,tag2,tag3"]]
result = arr[0][0].split(',')

#=> ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

**EDIT**

I found better solution with `flatten`

```
arr.flatten.first
#=> ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ruby's `split` method in your controller.
For example:

```
"tag1,tag2,tag3".split(',')
=> ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```